# Creating a list of arrays according to given rules

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, sparse-arrays

I want to create a list of matrices from the following rules:

1. All matrices of the list have diagonal equal to zero.
2. The first element of the list is a 2x2 matrix, having elements are given by

   ```
   S2 = SparseArray[{{1, 2} -> 1, {2, 1} -> 0}]
   ```

   The matrix is `{{0, 1}, {0, 0}}`;
3. The next element of the list is a 3x3 matrix. The elements in this matrix are taken from the elements of `S2` with the addition of `Subscript[A, 1, 3]`, `Subscript[A, 2, 3]`, `Subscript[A, 3, 1]` and `Subscript[A, 3, 2]`.

   The matrix is given by

   ```
   S3 = 
     {{0, 1, Subscript[A, 1, 3]}, 
      {0, 0, Subscript[A, 3, 3]}, 
      {Subscript[A, 3, 1], Subscript[A, 3, 2],0}}
   ```
4. The third element of the list is a 4x4 matrix called `S4`. The elements of `S4` are those from `S3` with additional elements `Subscript[B, 1, 4]`, `Subscript[B, 2, 4]`, `Subscript[B, 3, 4]`, `Subscript[B, 4, 1]`, `Subscript[B, 4, 2]`, `Subscript[B, 3, 3]`. The matrix is given by

   ```
   S4 = 
     {{0, 1, Subscript[A, 1, 3], Subscript[B, 1, 4]}, 
      {0, 0, Subscript[A, 2, 3], Subscript[B, 2, 4]}, 
      {Subscript[A, 3, 1], Subscript[A, 3, 2], 0, Subscript[B, 3, 4]}, 
      {Subscript[B, 4, 1], Subscript[B, 4, 2], Subscript[B, 4, 3], 0}}`
   ```

   and so on ....

I would like to use this process to build a list of 25 elements, corresponding the letters A – Z. I am thinking along the lines of

```
Table[SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 0, {i_, j_} -> f[i, j]}, {n, n}], {n, 25}],
```

but I have not found a function `f[i, j]` that does what I want.

Please, somebody help me.

Comment: I couldn't understand what exactly your rules are, but it seems that you do. Why not construct the matrix manually, then do `ArrayRules[SparseArray[yourMatrix]]` to discover the rules?

Comment: Also, you'll run into problems with many uppercase letters that have a reserved meaning, like `C`, `D`, `E`, `I`, `K` and so on

Comment: In fact, I can replace the letters A-> Z by Greek letters. I'll look calmly at ArrayRules. Thank you @yohbs

Answer (score 5):

In what you posted, I see no point in beginning with a sparse matrix.  The resulting matrices will not be sparse.  And since you want all of them, you want the biggest.  And since all of them are submatrices of the biggest, we can just create the biggest and then extract the submatrices.  So, if I have understood your request, you can use

```
bigmat[sqmat_, symbols_] := 
 With[{d = Length[sqmat], slen = Length[symbols]},
  Array[Function[{r, k}, If[r <= d && k <= d, sqmat[[r, k]],
     If[r == k, 0, Subscript[symbols[[Max[r, k] - d]], r, k]]]],
   {d + slen, d + slen}]]
```

to make the big matrix, and then use `Part` to pull out whichever of the submatrices you want.  E.g.,

```
startMatrix = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}};
symbolSet = {mA, mB, mC};
bigmat[startMatrix, symbolSet][[;; #, ;; #]] & /@ Range[2, 5]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Alan, How  can I, instead of using mA, mB and mC, use a large list of random integers while maintaining the same logic?

Comment: @SAC When you get an acceptable answer, it is courtesy to accept it.  (Details: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)  When you have a separate question, etiquette says that it should be asked as a separate question.  I would nevertheless try to answer your follow-on question here, except that I cannot understand it.  How are you relating the symbolic matrix to these "random integers"?

Answer (score 0):

I can write something similar using SparseArray

```
nmax = 5; (*number max of the dimension last matrix of the list*)
d = 2; (*dimension of the initial matrix*)
startMatrix = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}};(*initial matrix*)
q = Table[
  RandomInteger[{1, i - 1}], {i, d + 1, 
   nmax}];(*List of Random Integer in interval [1,n-1], where n is a \
variable which characterize the dimension of the matrix *)
f[i_, j_] := 
 If[i <= d && j <= d, startMatrix[[i, j]], 
  If[j > i, With[{s = q[[j - d]]}, Subscript[\[Xi], i, s]], 
   With[{p = q[[i - d]]}, Subscript[\[Xi], p, 
    j]]]](*The rule for construction of the matrix*)
m = Table[
   SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 0, {i_, j_} -> f[i, j]}, {n, n}], {n, d, 
    nmax}];(*The list of the matrices*)
Table[MatrixForm[m[[i]]], {i, 
  4}](*See the Matrix Form of the list of matrices*)
```